# How to pass additional arguments to a ZSH function?

Tags: zsh

I have created a small function in ZSH. I would like to pass additional arguments to `rga` in the function once in a while. I was able to use the positional argument in the command but how to pass additional arguments to `rga` if and when needed?

```
function magazine() {
    rga -i --sort path --after-context=1 --before-context=1 "$1" Magazines/
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I added the question in a haste. I read the documentation and found that I can use `$@` to pass multiple arguments to the function.

```bash
function magazine() {
    rga -i --sort path --after-context=1 --before-context=1 $@ Magazines/
}
```

Now I can use something like:

```bash
$ magazine -w "World"
```

Comment: Use `"$@"` instead of `$@`.

Comment: @Philippe The quotes aren't strictly needed with zsh. Though it does no harm to use them.

Comment: (technically they're needed if you want to preserve empty elements of an array)

Comment: @Shawn : Even in zsh, the quotes are needed when you want to pass arrays. Try it with `f() { echo $# }`  and `arr=(a "" b)`. If you call `f $arr` or the equivalent `f $arr[@]`, you get 2 printed. If you call `f "$arr[@]"`, you get 3.

Comment: @user1934428 That's the empty elements I referred to.

Comment: I didn't add the quotes and everything seems to be working fine. I will not be doing advanced like passing arrays hence I will keep it simple.